# Spring scope in Dropwizard App

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

If I have the following configuration in a Spring project, and different parts of the app get different instances of ServiceA, will I still have a concurrency problem because all instances of ServiceA will be sharing a single instance of dataSource?  Do I need to simply know if BasicDataSource is threadsafe?  If it is, then I am ok, if it is not, then I will have threading issues?

```
<bean id="serviceA" name="serviceA" class="com.company.ServiceA" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" name="dataSource"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${dbConnectionUrl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="${connectionSize}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="${maxConnectionSize}" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have any issues unless you are using some very strange datasource. All your beans in Spring should be stateless except for session beans. Out of the box beans from Spring will be like this. If you do this in your code as well you won't have any problems. All your singleton beans could have been essentially static but this would make them less or not testable, as you would have a tough time mocking them. The other issue besides concurrency with having state in your beans which are not session beans is if you try to scale up your application and deploy multiple instances of the same webapp, it will most likely fall over. Typically you don't have your beans use the datasource, (although you may have reasons too). You usually work with a session factory and just get current session from your session factory which has a reference to the datasource. Or using an entity manager which is similar.

**Edit** To addresss the comments. A stateless bean (no variables) is inherently thread safe. So unless your bean has variables as many threads as you want can access it at the same time. Even if a bean is accessing a database this is the case, it will still be thread safe because the database handles all the concurrency data problems for you. I'm not too sure what you mean by context switching? Two requests may run through the same bean but they will have different sessions from the session factory, there will be no shared state so there will be no concurrency issues.

With the session factory you'll just have to read up on that. Typically you would use something like hibernate for mapping classes to a database, and your session is like your link to the database. This handles all sorts of aspects for working with a database for you. The vast majority of Spring apps are like this. If you google Spring MVC hibernate you will see what I mean.

I believe there is a big debate about whether or not a REST service still can have sessions but I can't really comment on that, although I know you can just pass a session id in the URL, but any way if you are really not having any sessions and no variables you won't have any concurrency issues unless you are referencing a very very strange library, simply because no problems can exist if there is no shared state.

Comment: "all the beans should be stateless".  How does this protect me? default scope is singleton.  Therefore when Spring handles two requests, potentially wouldn't both requests run through the same bean?  Wouldn't it be possible to context switch in the middle of handling a request?

Comment: " Typically you don't have your beans use the datasource, (although you may have reasons too). You usually work with a session factory and just get current session from your session factory which has a reference to the datasource"  - I didn't understand what you were saying here.  Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: actually, I'm doing a REST service here, so there are no sessions to speak of.

Comment: But don't mix up the hibernate session with the HTML session.